# Concept of API and ABI

Tags: operating-system

I am confused between **API**(Application Programming Interface) and **ABI**(Application Binary Interface) can somebody explain me what is the concept of these two and their difference?

Comment: Look into wikipedia and come back with a specific question.

Answer (score 5):

An API defines the objects and methods that a module makes available to its clients, at the source-code level. How do you instantiate its objects? What arguments do you need to pass to its methods, and what do they return? In general, when you want to know what library functions are available and how to use them, you're asking about an API.

The ABI is a lower-level concept. It defines the bits and bytes that are passed between a module and its clients. What format are they in? Are they pushed onto the stack, passed in registers, or stored elsewhere? Does the stack need to be cleaned up when a function returns, and if so, who's responsible for tending to it?

*Totally Silly but Instructive Example:*

Consider a library function that multiplies two integers:

```
long long multiply(unsigned int multiplicand, long multiplier);
```

Its API specifies that you call it with two arguments (an unsigned integer and a signed long integer), and it returns a signed double-precision long integer.

Its ABI might specify that you use it like this:

- Push the return address on the stack as an absolute 64-bit address, in MSB to LSB order. The program will continue execution at that address when the function completes.
- Push a 32-bit value onto the stack in MSB to LSB order. It represents the unsigned multiplicand.
- Store a 64-bit value in the accumulator register, in MSB to LSB order. It represents the signed multiplier in two's-complement form.
- Jump to address 0xADDADD relative to the beginning of the program to execute the function.
- Upon completion, take the first 4 bytes on the stack and append the first 4 bytes of the value in the accumulator register to create the signed 64-bit product, in LSB to MSB order, in one's-complement format. The caller must remove the 4 bytes from the stack, as well as the 4-byte multiplicand and the 8-byte return address, to restore the stack.

Protip: If I were you, I'd find another math library. This one's terrible! :-)